# Android Web Service connenction Error

Tags: android, web-services, tomcat

I created Java web services and trying to connect with android code.I am getting the service running but android app is showing error in soap object creating for namespace and method name.I did all the changes and everything is correct namespace,method name,URL all is correct.But I don't know what is wrong can anyone help me out...!
My android code is----->
showing error in
-"SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);"

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:training/searchCompanyInfo";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "searchCompanyInfo";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:training/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost/attest/CompanyInfoService?wsdl";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println(NAMESPACE);
        System.out.println(METHOD_NAME);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


            SoapPrimitive s = response;
            String str = s.toString();
            String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);

            for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){
            tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
           }
            setContentView(tv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the error message / stacktrace

Comment: Did you include the SoapLibary to your project?

Comment: @Ion Aalbers I did that in the first but I am not able to see the error its showing some alert..

Answer (score 0):

In Android, You cannot perform network operation on the main thread, You need to execute your soap request in a background thread. Please read up on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).